# How can I write a function that would update any missing specific post metadata?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I was given an assignment that follows a scenario for basketball players. It contains a custom post type 'player' that exist with a meta field call 'player_external_id' assuming all players has a very unique ID other than WordPress ID.

All players will have a page on the third party website with the following structure
"http://example.com/channel/{player_external_id}"

A new meta field 'player_tv_url' was added to the 'player' custom post and all new players drafted for the upcoming season have the proper value set.

They needed to update any missing 'player_tv_url' post metadata and I was asked to write a code that would accomplish that.

Here is the code I submitted:

```php
function check_post_update_meta ($post_id, $key, $value) {
    $response = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
    if ($response == $value) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $response = update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
    }
}
```

How would I trigger the execution of the code?

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'player_tv_url', $value);
```

I received feedback saying there were components missing in my code. I thought I was heading in the right path. I don't know what went wrong? I would like to know what is exactly missing in my code in order to fix it.

Comment: "there were components missing in my code" - well, is that your actual code? You're missing the `$` here: `$response == value`, and you're also missing the `y` here: `update_post_meta($post_id, $ke, $value)` - note the `$ke`, and the "update" is also misspelled in the function name: `check_post_udpate_meta` ..

Comment: @SallyCJ - That was not the actual code that I submitted. I already corrected the errors you pointed out. This still doesn't resolve anything. There are components that are still missing and the entire code is still wrong.

Comment: In that case, then your code looks OK to me, and as for executing the code, you can try using the [`save_post` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/). But this - "update any missing 'player_tv_url' post metadata" - isn't clear enough to me - update to what value exactly and when should the update be done? They should explain or give a pointer regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your code may be returning an empty string or false, then comparing it to another empty string or false thus returning true.

```
function check_post_update_meta ($post_id, $key, $value) {

   // response can receive post meta array, or '' or false
   $response = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);

    // isset checks for data, so in case $response is empty if() will not evaluate true
    if( isset($response) ){

        if ($response == $value) {

            return true;

        } else {

            $response = update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would then have to do something in case $response is empty or false, adding some code after the first if.

Comment: How would you trigger the execution of the code?

Comment: You have to call check_post_update_meta() from somewhere in your site, it can be a cron job, a hook or some other function.